# Nothing is printed while using concurrent.futures

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I want to make a process run parallelly, so I am using concurrent.futures . The problem is that it does not execute the function hello().

```
import time
import concurrent.futures
def hello(name):
    print(f'hello {name}')
    sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1=time.perf_counter()
    names=["Jack","John","Lily","Stephen"]


    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(hello,names)

    t2=time.perf_counter()
    print(f'{t2-t1} seconds')
```

Output

```
0.5415315 seconds
```

Comment: I got a totally different output, for me it waits the amount if time given in `sleep` befor showing the perf_counter time

Comment: @azro did it print the names?

Answer (score 1):

After going through the [concurrent.futures documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)  I found that ProcessPoolExecutor does not work in the interactive interpreter. So you need to make a file and run it via command prompt/bash shell.